# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable design feedback and patience.

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

[Main site favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/travel/img/favicon.ico)

[Meta site favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/travelmeta/img/favicon.ico)

We have also themed the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here), [twitter](https://twitter.com/stacktravel) account and email newsletter template for this site.

I know there were some opinions on the new logo design. I'd like the community to give it some time to sink in. The reason I didn't go with a more generic design is because I don't think in the long run, it'd make this community's branding stand out. I've learned my lesson from several other sites I designed in the past. For example, on [webapps.se](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), at the time I thought the cloud icon was the best fit. It was the most recognizable, but then a lot of other site/apps also used the same shape. This is how I feel about the first version of the logo, using a compass and a single push pin design.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a **new post** here on Meta and tag it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community! I really appreciate all the help you provided during this design process!

Comment: Is it intentional that only 2 map pins from the logo show on meta?

Comment: @waxeagle hm there are should be. although the top one is a bit light if your gamma is high. I'll tweak that some.

Comment: Fantastic design! My first impressions cruising around the new design are very positive. Does that mean [we](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) are next in line?

Comment: @Caleb thank you. Yes I'll be starting on your site next, along with another site design.