# New design: CSS styling bugs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Unless you've been hiking in the Andes for the last few weeks, you know that the [new site design is now live](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/new-design-launched). Here are a few small things that don't merit starting their own question, so I'll just put them together.

---

`1.` When inserting new image, the color combination on the `from the web` button on mouse hover makes it hard to read.

[image]

---

`2.` The `?` button to bring out the help menu when writing posts has a white instead of transparent background when clicked -- see image below.

[image]

Comment: I was not hiking the Andes, but tonight I was struck dumb by the novelty (at least for me) of the new design. I sort of like it, but is there a thread which I could read to understand the reasons for the change?

Comment: @Paola: It's part of the Stack Exchange site graduation process, and it signifies that a site leaves beta and is ready for prime time. The whole process is too long to describe in this space, but check [this SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) for some insight on site graduation. The blog is also a good resource to get familiar with Stack Exchange culture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed these two bugs on our dev server. The changes will go live after our next production build. We typically build daily after midnight EST.