# Main site tab icon still for beta?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design

I'm still seeing the **beta** tab icon for the Main site...
*Why*?
(I see the new design on the Meta site)

Comment: are you still seeing the old icon?

Comment: yup, still the Beta icon.

Comment: I'm marking this as status-completed since it's just matter of time for the old image to be un-cached. Most people are seeing the new one by now.

Answer (score 4):

See [this post-launch post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/new-design-launched). You'll need to do a hard refresh (F5) of the page, or manually refresh the favicons, as described in the post.

Comment: But I never opened the site while it was in beta.
Today is the first time I'm opening it...

Comment: @Siddhartha - weird. But try pressing Ctrl+Shift+R to force a reload, or F5.  See if it goes away?

Comment: @MarkMayo - I'm on a Mac, so it's Command+Shift+R for me, still, it didn't work...

Comment: @Siddhartha well that's just weird! Er...clear cache? What happens if you ... er, on a PC you'd right click and view image, so that just the image is showing, and then force a reload on that, then go back?

Comment: @Siddhartha: Did you just refresh the page or did you follow the post mindcorrosive linked which gives instructions on how to refresh the logos individually? I had to do it the second way myself.

Comment: @Siddhartha you must be behind a proxy, you are getting the icon from the proxy cache.. you can not do anything about it, just wait until the proxy cache recycles then you will get the new icon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still seeing the Beta apple-touch-icon.png as well. But I confirmed the image file I checked in is the new one. After talking to our dev, he said it's cached on the server side by our CDN. A lot people are seeing the new one already. I think it's just matter of time when the new icon propagates completely.