# Travel.SE's birthday?

Tags: discussion

I know this might be off-topic but I have no idea where else can I ask this. I am a relatively newer member here and I've been completely mesmerized by the SE network. So out of curiosity when was Travel.SE formed:

- Can someone give me a timeline of the Area 51 proposal
- When did it enter and exit Private Beta
- When did it exit Public Beta

Is there a date which people could call its birthday?

Comment: You could have a look at the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591?phase=beta) itself. They have some dates, although they are a little vague.

Comment: @drat They're quite vague. :( I was looking for something like 14th July 2010...

Comment: @AdityaSomani The info is there, just hover the text (see my answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the information is freely accessible via the [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel).

There are a few birthdays to mention

- First proposed: 17th of June 2010 (at 10:35:06)
- Commitment start: 29th of October 2010 (at 21:54:41)
- Private beta start: 21st of June 2011 (at 19:00:00)
- Public beta start: 28th of June 2011 (at 19:41:52)
- Launched: this date is not stored on Area 51 as far as I can see.

Hint: Hover the "N days/years ago" for exact date-time info.

Comment: Whooo!! :D I did not know you could just hover over it! Super Cool! :D

Comment: I am curious to learn why this answer was downvoted? Does it not answer the three bulletes in the question?

Comment: Launch was Jan 22, 2013 (See other answers)

Comment: @MarkMayo True, but that is not really the question.

Comment: @Bernhard I wasn't correcting you, I was just offering the launch date that you didn't have above - 'this date is not stored on Area 51'.

Comment: (and I upvoted, btw)

Comment: @MarkMayo I understand, and saw the other answer, but if I add it there, it can give the impression it can be found on Area 51, which it can't, as far as I can see :)

Answer (score 10):

The official launch was on

### January 22, 2013

Source: [New Design Launched](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/new-design-launched)

Answer (score 8):

Travel.SE's birthdate is:

### June 21st, 2011

How did I know that? I checked the date of [the first question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-caribbean-cruises-for-october) in the site, and the [first registered user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) in the site as well. Both show the same date. Anyway this is the private beta birthday, if you want the public beta birthdate then add one week to that (**June 28th, 2011**).

Comment: Upsettingly, he didn't ask or answer any questions :(